# How to Call variables in VS Code Terminal (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

Can anyone help out with the below. In some lectures I am watching the lecturer uses the vs code in built terminal to call upon variables after running a .py file. However I cant seem to get the same functionality in my VS Code setup.

I have the below simple program to showcase my issue:

```
a = "hello world"

print(a)
```

My steps:

1. Run program (F5)
2. Attempt to call variable 'a' in terminal with the expectation it would return 'hello world'.

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop>  & 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51586' '--' 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\hello.py' 
hello world
PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop> a
a : The term 'a' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ a
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (a:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This prints 'hello world' (via the print statement) as expected by my expectation is when I also call variable 'a' in the terminal it should return/show 'hello world' as well.

Note that my python paths are set (Windows 11) so I don't believe this is the issue.

Comment: I can tell you the problem is that you’re executing the Python program in the PowerShell terminal, and when it’s done it drops you back into PowerShell, where any Python expressions will of course have no meaning. What I cannot tell you is whether VSC has an execute-Python-script-and-stay-in-Python-interactive-interpreter mode.

Comment: are you sure the lecturer is using the built in terminal tab and not the debug console tab of vscode?

Comment: is he using a python REPL by just typing `python` in the terminal and then he gets a prompt of `>>>`

Comment: if he is using python expressions is it at a breakpoint, then he is using the debug console. without a link to the movie we can't tell

Answer (score 0):

If you see that variables can be directly called in the terminal, I suppose that he types `python` in cmd.

In this way, you can see `>>>`.

[image]